# CSS - slide up a div on click that is not visible before that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beqswr69/63/) of a page where I would like an on click event to animate `scrollTop` to the div `.panel-two`. I have tried some jQuery plugins but nothing has worked. The problem I have is that I can't use scrollTop if the div is not visible and can't animate `scrollIntoView`.

This is the html:

```
<body>

  <!-- Close button -->
  <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>

  <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="bg">
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-one">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
          ligula pharetra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-two">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
        ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I am planning to have a slider in the `.panel-one` div with images where a click of an image would then scroll the associated div up to take over the screen.

The `.panel-one` div needs to take over the whole screen and a user shouldn't be able to scroll down. Only once the `.panel-two` div has slid up on a click of an image should the user then be able to scroll back up to reveal the `.panel-one` div again. `.panel-two` should then disappearing below the screen.

Comment: I dont understand what is your goal. Do you want to create some sort of "Scroll down"/"See more" button that would scroll page to the next section/div/panel ?

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help but I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.  Have you seen any working example that you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is a bit late, but I guess this will help you have the image slider put in at `panel-one`:

1. First I hide the scrollbar:

   ```
   $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
   ```
2. On `panel-one` click, you can animate to `panel-two`:

   ```
   $(".panel-one").on('click', function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('.panel-two').offset().top
     }, 1000, function() {
       $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
   });
   ```

   also not forgetting to switch on `overflow` at the end of the animation.
3. Now add a `scroll` listener to hide the scrollbar once the user scrolls upto the top of `panel-one`:

   ```
   $(document).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
       $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
   });
   ```

See demo below:

```js
$(".close-button").on('click', function() {
  if ($("#offCanvas").css('margin-left') < '0') {
    $("#offCanvas").css('margin-left', '0');
    $(".panel").css('margin-left', '50%');
    $("#bg").css('margin-left', '50%');
  } else {
    $("#offCanvas").css('margin-left', '-50%');
    $(".panel").css('margin-left', '0');
    $("#bg").css('margin-left', '0');
  }
});

$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

$(".panel-one").on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.panel-two').offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  });
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
#offCanvas {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.close-button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#bg {
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/500?random');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: zoom 10s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.panel {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}
.panel-fixed {
  z-index: 1;
}
.panel-inner {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-fixed .panel-inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
/* Base */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-two {
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <!-- Close button -->
  <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Foundation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Dot</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">ZURB</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Com</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Slash</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sites</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="bg">
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-one">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
          ligula pharetra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-two">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit
        ligula pharetra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Leff let me know your thoughts on this answer, thanks!